# PHP SQLSRV PDO number of results

Tags: php, pdo, sqlsrv

Having issues returning number of results in PHP SQLSRV PDO connection, when I try $stmt->rowCount(); get -1 result, really don't get it.

```
...
...
...
if(empty($region)){
    $query2 = "SELECT [QuotID], [QuotNumber], CreationDate, QuotDate
    FROM [dbo].[vQuotaion]
    GROUP BY [QuotID]
        ,[QuotNumber]
        ,[CreationDate]
        ,[QuotDate]
    HAVING CreationDate >='".$fdate."' AND CreationDate <='".$edate."' AND  ProType = 'OPSFi' ORDER BY CreationDate DESC";
    $stmt2 = $conn->query( $query2 );           
} else {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
...
...
...
<?php
if(empty($stmt2)){
    echo '';
    }else{
        while ($result = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        bla bla bla;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: [*If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.*](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: [*Great, while using MySQL5, the only way to get the number of rows after doing a PDO SELECT query is to either execute a separate SELECT COUNT(*) query (or to do count($stmt->fetchAll()), which seems like a ridiculous waste of overhead and programming time.
*](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#78338)

Comment: Make use of prepared statements seeing as you are using PDO.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the rows without a separate query you can do this with PDO:

```
$rows = $stmt2->fetchAll();
$num_rows = count($rows);
```

There is no way to directly count rows when using a `SELECT` statement with PDO ***for all database drivers***. You could create a function using the code above if you need to retrieve counts regularly.

### Warning!

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row count of a `select` query with the PDO versions of the sqlsrv drivers however, like the standard version of the drivers (non-PDO), you have to specify a scrollable cursor. Like so:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->rowCount();
```

The default cursor used is `PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY` which, when `rowCount()` is used, returns `-1`.

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/pdostatement-rowcount).

Comment: It would work on a toy table with 10 records but would doom any real server.